# How to get row and column from index?

Tags: matrix

I'm drawing a *HUGE* blank here.

Everything I've found is about getting an index from a given row and column, but how do I get a row and a column from an index?

The row is easy: `(int)(index / width)`.

My brain is suffering massive bleed trying to compute the column.

Shame on me.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

For a zero-based index, the two operations are, where `width` is the width of the structure:

```
row    = index / width
column = index % width
```

Those are for C using integers, where the division rounds down and the `%` modulo operator gives the remainder. If you're not using C, you may have to translate to the equivalent operations.

If you don't *have* a modulo operator, you can use:

```
row    = index / width
column = index - (row * width)
```

Comment: Damn you right, my nomenclature is a mess, I also call it a row, lol, just now I found a possible stupid solution: row = index - (col * width), of course, yours are the one I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I would consider the x position a column and the y a row, so this is backwards.

Comment: @CodyMace: yes, I'd made it clear in  the answer that they were the wrong way around. However, you're right. In order to avoid confusion, and because the OP has stated they got it the wrong way around, I've tidied up both the question and this answer to correct the issue. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Python has a built-in function named [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) that computes and returns both of these values.

Comment: This saved my brain from thinking too hard.  Thanks.

Comment: That's good to know, martineau, assuming you're using Python :-) Unfortunately, there's nothing in the question indicating that, and the vast majority of questions from this asker seem to pertain to C, C++ and C#. So *possibly* not relevant here.

Comment: What is int in the above formula? That's never defined anywhere. I'm assuming width is the number of columns is that right?

Comment: @BernoulliLizard, it' an operator rather than a variable, meant to indicate that the result should be rounded down to the nearest integer. And `width` is the number of columns, as you assume. Both those points were in the original question but I'll adjust the answer to clarify ...

Answer (score 24):

Paxdiablo's answer is the right one. If someone needs the reverse process to get index from row and column:

```
index = (row * width) + column
```

Comment: Came here in hopes of a reverse formula, got one. Thanks! For people getting wrong values: I had to do `((row - 1) * width) + (col - 1)`, to make `row` and `col` zero-based.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
typealias ColumnRowType = (column:Int, row:Int)

func indexToColumnRow(index:Int, columns:Int) -> ColumnRowType
{
    let columnIndex = (index % columns)
    let rowIndex = /*floor*/(index / columns)    // we just cast to an `Int`

    return ColumnRowType(columnIndex, rowIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, with a column offset of 1, this is a way to do it

```
int offset=1;
column = Math.floorDiv(location-offset , 3)+offset;
row = ( (location-offset) %3 )+offset ;
```