# How to get diagonal and antidiagonal number

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

If you can get the row and col from a 1-dimensional array, given the width and formulas below. how would you get the diagonals and anti-diagonals? my example is trivial. Looking for something that scales to MxN, and is general.

### pseudo code

```
A = array[26];
width = 5;
row(index)    = floor((index / width))
column(index) = index % width
digonal(index) = //???
antidigonal(index) = //???
```

### example values

```
row 5:  26  27  28  29  30
row 4:  21  22  23  24  25
row 3:  16  17  18  19  20
row 2:  11  12  13  14  15
row 1:  6   7   8   9   10
row 0:  1   2   3   4   5
--------------------------      
column: 0   1   2   3   4

diag 0: 1               
diag 1: 6, 2                
diag 2: 3, 7, 11                
diag 3: 4, 8, 12, 16                
etc.            

antidiag 0: 5               
antidiag 1: 4, 10               
antidiag 2: 3, 9, 15
etc.
```

Related to [How to get row and column from index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821899/how-to-get-row-and-column-from-index)

Comment: what is the diagonal of an array?  what is the antidiagonal?

Comment: How would you do it by hand, now convert that to code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. What's the input and what's the output for what you're trying to compute? Do you want the index corresponding to a particular position on a diagonal or antidiagonal? Or do you want to somehow go from an index to another index on the diagonal/antidiagonal? Or something else?

Comment: Diagonal is where `row` equals to `col`

Comment: ok, I get it, the width indicates that we in fact have a 2 dimensional array stored in just 1 dimension

Comment: Please edit your question to include some examples as it's not clear exactly what you're asking. What outputs would you expect for a given set of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the numbering in your example....

Diagonal k indices are:

```
i * width + k - i
```

for i ranging from 0 to k.

For example, to print diagonal k,

```
for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i * (width - 1) + k]);
}
```

The above loop is written in java, the javascript loop is similar.

This gives the diagonals from diagonal 0 to diagonal width - 1.
For the remaining diagonals, you use for each k (where k ranges from width to 2 * width - 1)

```
for(int i = k - (width - 1); i < width - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i * (width - 1) + k]);
}
```

For example, if you have width 5, then use k = 0 to 4 in the first for loop, then use k = 6 to 9 in the second for loop, to get your 9 diagonals.

For the anti diagonal indices, just subtract each diagonal value from width - 1

```
width - 1 - (i * width + k - i)
```

for i ranging as indicated in the above for loops

Comment: Good start but I need the reverse. Givin the index, what is the diagonal. Two index's on the same diagonal should have the same value.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.  The for loop above prints out each diagonal.  For diagonal 0, replace k with 0.  For diagonal 1, replace k with 1.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "two indexes on the same diagonal should have the same value".  You have an array, it has indexes, if two indexes have the same value you are talking about the same array element.

Answer (score 0):

found a way

```
diagonal: function (s) {
  return row(s) - col(s);
},

antidiagonal: function (s) {
  return row(s) + col(s);
},
```