# Get row number from grid index

Tags: javascript

I got this grid with each square's index showing in the middle (0-63):

[image: grid]

Then I have a function which needs to return the **row** number when I pass it an index.

**The row number can be between 0-7.**

Function that should do this, with a poor attempt at retrieving the row number currently inside it:

```
function (index) {
  return Math.floor(index / 7);
}
```

Example outputs (index -> row output):

0 -> 0

5 -> 0

7 -> 0

8 -> 1

23 -> 2

35 -> 4

43 -> 5

63 -> 7

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821899/how-to-get-row-and-column-from-index) which I thought was about the same issue as I'm having but the answer there did not give the correct output so I must've misunderstood it.

How can I change my function to return the correct row number from a given index?

Comment: What unexpected answer does the current function give? It seems to be correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to divide by column count which are 8:

```
function (index) {
  return Math.floor(index / 8);
}
```

Comment: Well, I never was a math genius.. Thanks :D